# Asciidoc: How can I format text in a user defined attribute?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

When writing `H~2~O` in the text of an asciidoc document, it is rendered "H subscript(2) O",
However trying to define an attribute: `:water: H~2~O` and refer to the attribute in the text as `{water}` it is replaced by the verbatim definition of `:water:` or `H~2~O`. (the subscript formatting is not processed). And the question is: Can I define attributes  with text formatting? (a workaround would be to use 'sed' for example, but it would be more elegant to do within asciidoc, if possible).

Answer (score 5):

From [this page of the documentation](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/attributes/attribute-entry-substitutions/):

> inline formatting in an attribute value isn’t interpreted

However, this can be changed by using the inline pass macro.

For example:

```
:water: pass:quotes[H~2~O]
```